# Some Italian Expressions about Turks

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

I've heard some of the Italian expressions about the Turks, like below ones:

- *Mamma li turchi!*
- *Fumare come un turco*
- *Bestemmia come un turco*
- *Puzza come un turco*

I was wondering, where and why these expressions found a place for themselves in Italiano, which means what are the origins of these expressions?

Comment: Turco: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/turco.shtml - http://cittafuturamaglie.blogspot.it/2013/04/il-perche-di-certi-modi-di-dire-fumare.html

Comment: I have never heard the last one.

Comment: The Turks were a real threat to everyone living on Italy's coast for centuries. As such, they are the default for any association with barbaric, dangerous, dirty, blasphemous etc. Kind of like now every despised and/or feared stranger is a 'Marocchino', as Moroccan troops under the French flag were responsible of atrocities during the occupation following World War II.

Comment: Grazie @Charo, ma no, sono Turco, e voglio capire loro.

Comment: @Prometheus: Anyway, I think David's post is an opinion and not a real answer to the question.

Comment: @Charo: Certo, non era una risposta, ma il parallelo con i “marocchini” non è del tutto insensato (e ci furono veramente [episodi gravi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marocchinate) in Italia), nel senso che un tempo – da qualche parte tuttora – si usava questo epiteto indipendentemente dalla vera nazionalità della persona di cui si parlava.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Mamma li turchi!

In the end of 1700, a group of Ottomans arrived in Sicily and during a lunch at Palazzo Comitini, a Turkish admiral was caught beating a girl, so everyone, indignant, started a real "Turkish hunt" and the kids ran down the streets shouting "Mamma li turchi!" that means "Mom the Turks!" as "Mom I've found a Turkish!"

> Fumare come un turco

Turkish people during Ottoman Empire were associated with arab habits, one of this was the use to smoke shisha/narghile/hooka/water pipe.

> Bestemmia come un turco
>
> Puzza come un turco

These last two sentence has no historical meaning, they are just made associating concepts. "Bestemmia come un turco" may be the association of Turkish/Arab language that may hear rough to an Italian and may give the idea of someone cursing ("bestemmiare" means "to curse to God"). The last one is actually racist and I've never heard/seen it, a better and not racist way to say the same concept is "Puzza come un maiale/cane/capra" ("He/She smells like a pig/dog/goat").

Another example of association of two concepts may be "Mi capisci o parlo cinese?" that means "Do you understand me or do I speak Chinese?"

EDIT: As suggestion from DaG it can be assumed that the sentence "Bestemmiare come un turco" can be interpreted as a memory of the ancient fights against Arabs were Christians and Muslims fought against each other. The sentence so could be intepreted as the Turkey inhabitants cursed to God to evidence the fact their don't trust in Christian God and so they curses would be more evidenced. And I quote from the user:

> But in this particular case, I believe it is safer to assume Turks where put together with every other “infidel” people who blasphemed in the sense of saying things contrary to the Christian God. If it were just a matter of harsh sounds, to an Italian ear, Germans, Russians or even Greeks might be sound as cursing too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of all, @dulindraxe. Can you also please provide the source that you've found them?

Comment: The "Fumare come un turco" source comes from a friend of mine degreeded in History and other sources suggest that this sentence may come from the excessive use of tobacco (through water pipe) after a years of straight prohibition empire, like [this](http://www.focus.it/cultura/storia/perche-si-dice-fumare-come-un-turco).

Comment: If you look for "Mamma li turchi!" on Internet you will always find the same story with historical proofs. Also in the city where I live this sentence was used a lot in the past and I've always heard the same story told by old people. Moreover I'm sure the other sentences aren't "typical Italian expressions" because they surely are just associations.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: A friend “degreeded in History” isn't an actual source. If there so many sources for these versions, would you please find one for each saying and insert them in your answer?

Comment: I think _puzza come una capra_ is more common than _cane/maiale_.

Comment: As for “bestemmiare come un turco”, I'd say it's more likely to be a reference to Turks being not Christians and so seen at one time as some kind of infidels.

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes sure, it depends where you live actually but I took your suggestion and edited the answer

Comment: @DaG I put the second sentence source in the comments, I just think a speech of an histortian would be enough proof. "Bestemmiare come un turco" and "Puzzare come un turco" CAN NOT be Italian expressions: these are just associations the brain does selecting stereotypes/habits

Comment: Yes, an article or lecture of a historian would be proof enough indeed. Who is the historian?

Comment: *Bestemmiare come un turco* is mentioned at page 245 of Carlo Lupucci, *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* (Garzanti-Vallardi, 1979), with the remark “ricordo delle antiche lotte con gli Arabi”. See also [here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/bestemmiare.shtml). So it is definitely an Italian expression, @dulindraxe. I trust the rest of your research is better than this.

Comment: @DaG Since he is young you won't find him on the internet and it would be useless to tell you his name, but I can give you more links like [this](http://www.agendalugano.ch/episodes/409/perche-si-dice-fumare-come-un-turco) , [this](http://www.linkuaggio.com/2013/12/perche-si-dice-fumare-come-un-turco.html) and [this](http://genio.virgilio.it/domanda/60108/perche-si-dice-fumare-come-turco) .

Comment: I am glad you got persuaded that “a friend of mine says that” is not a source. Now, if just you could integrate the sources in you answer (and also something to substantiate the “mamma” one), it would become a quite good one.

Comment: @DaG "I trust the rest of your research is better than this." I don't want to do half the job, but I'm really sure the sentence "Bestemmiare come un turco" has no history relation even if someone may have used it. I'm pretty sure it's just an expression preserved and now has no meaning (I liked your comment anyway, it's culture improvement)

Comment: Thanks, @dulindraxe. By “has no history relation” do you mean that Turks don't actually curse? It may very well be and I have no reason to doubt it, but this is beyond the scope of this site and this question. I just pointed out that *bestemmiare come un turco* is a long-standing, widespread, recorded Italian expression.

Comment: I prefer to see "Bestemmiare come un turco" in this way: in the past when Italian language was considered one of the most elegant like French, Spanish or Latin, someone hearing an Arab speaking or a Turkish one (remember that Ottoman Empire was where now there are "arab speaking countries"), may have considered "Turkish/Arab language" (even if we know that Turkish isn't an arab language) to be a harsh and not comprensible language, resembling the intention of someone really angry or shouting. A writer could have used this descrition to create the sentence "Bestemmiare come un turco".

Comment: Also @DaG this stereotypes happen with other cultures like German one or Slavic (you can see how social environment and parody amde every German speaking "always angry" or every Russian speaking as the speaker was going to treaten the listener). This happens since long time ago and will always happen

Comment: Sorry for grammar errors, I should have re-read my answers...

Comment: "This happens since long time ago and will always happen". An example is the Ancient Greek word "Engortynòomai" that means "Being stupid as a Cretan who lives in Gortyna"...which it has no meaning but Gortyna inhabitants were often mocked in Ancient Greek jokes

Comment: Your conjecture is likely-sounding (and for the wider discourse you mention there is no better example, I believe, than the origin of the Greek term barbaros – Barbarian – as someone who babbles, i.e., cannot speak properly Greek). But in this particular case, I believe it is safer to assume Turks where put together with every other “infidel” people who *bestemmiavano* in the sense of saying things contrary to the Christian God. If it were just a matter of harsh sounds, to an Italian ear, Germans, Russians or even Greeks might be sound as cursing too.

Comment: @DaG I edited the answer to fit both hypotesis

Comment: "Puzza come un turco" doesn't exist

Comment: @DaG, please leave the answer as it is. You first tried to abused me with the sentence "**Did you Google them or do we need to do it for you?**", and then deleted it right after I gave a complaint about you. Now you are abusing the other users with changing their answers. I understand you may want to add something, and you can do it by adding new answer. So if you have an answer, do not hesitate and write it to downside, but if you don't, do not change others answers to fit in yours too.

Comment: Dear @Prometheus, I stand by my earlier comment (since your question doesn't show a modicum of previous research that SE sites require) and I didn't delete it; some moderator did. I am grateful to you for resurrecting it; I wouldn't have. I did not modify dulindrake's answer, as you can check by looking at the revisions' history. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Prometheus: I think this discussion has no sense here!

Comment: Yes, you are right about that, and sorry for misunderstanding @Charo . Sorry DaG

Comment: You're welcome, @Prometheus. Sometimes my brusque manners make me appear meaner than I am.